# How to flatten a two dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is an example. Values can be text, numbers, or more values.

```
var array = [[1,2],[ [3,4],[5,6] ],[1,2],[1,2]]
```

This is the result I want (Note [3,4],[5,6]).

```
var flattened = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,2],[1,2]]
```

Comment: What are you expecting, the expected result just doesn't have `var aa=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` to iterate the array a flatten the 1st level of sub-arrays. Wrap in another array all elements that are 1 dimension deep.

```js
const a = [[1,2],[[3,4],[3,4]],[1,2],[1,2]]

const result = a.flatMap(v => 
  Array.isArray(v[0]) ? v : [v] 
)

console.log(result)
```

Using reduce iterate the array. Combine the current element (`v`) with the accumulator (`acc`) by spreading (2 dimensions), or by add (1 dimension).

```js
const a = [[1,2],[[3,4],[3,4]],[1,2],[1,2]]

const result = a.reduce((acc, v) => 
  Array.isArray(v[0]) 
    ? [...acc, ...v] // 2d
    : [...acc, v] // 1d
, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the array with a simple reduce (if you have only one level of nesting)

```
const result = aa.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(Array.isArray(cur[0]))
    return [...acc, ...cur];
  return [...acc, cur];
}, []);
```